# ViewGroup clipChildren false not working

Tags: android, android-view, android-framelayout, viewgroup

I've a `FragmentActivity` that contains a `FrameLayout` working as a slide-up-menu container. That container has 2 Views, a `FrameLayout` where the sub-menus are inflated and a `View` that represents the slide-up-menu slide Y limit (ignore this View for this question, (1)LinearLayout [0,158][540,160]). 
I'm inflating a sub-menu (`FrameLayout`) that contains a `ViewPager` and a `LinearLayout`. The `LinearLayout` is the blue rectangle (header) with 3 circles in the image bellow, the `ViewPager` it's the grey one.
This header slides up or down at certain circumstances depending on the `ViewPager` currentItem, the following pictures illustrate the layout hierarchy:

[image: pic 1]
[image: pic2]

The red rectangle in the first picture represents the sub-menu inflated inside the slide-up-menu `FrameLayout`. The red rectangle in the second pictures represents the sub-menu header.
All `FrameLayouts` have this:

```
android:clipChildren="false"
```

But my header keeps getting clipped when it's translated up as you can see in the picture. Is it possible what I want to achieve? I'm I doing something wrong here?
The header has a zIndex = 1 for this example because it's supposed to have zIndex = 0 and the `ViewPager` zIndex = 1 to give the illusion that the header is translating up behind the `ViewPager` (and behind the slide-up-menu).
Thanks for your time.